# How to print unique elements and also count frequency in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table like the following,

```
Name  ActionCategory
Ana    1
Joe    2
Bob    1
Tom    3
Joe    4
Ana    5
...
```

I want to write a SQL that can find the unique names and count the num of appearance. Expected output like:

```
Name     Appearance
Ana      2
Joe      2
Bob      1
Tom      1
```

I'm able to print the unique names using the following sql, can some one tell me how to count the appearance?

```
SELECT 
   DISTINCT(Name) as UniqueNames
FROM
   tableName
```

Thanks

Comment: select Name,count(Name) as Appearance from table group by Name; hope this will work

Answer (score 2):

You can try below using aggregate function count() and apply group by

```
SELECT 
   Name,count(Name) as UniqueNames
FROM
   tableName
group by Name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group by`

```
   SELECT Name , count(Name) as Appearance 
      FROM yourtable
    GROUP BY NAME
```

Comment: `Count(Name)` not `count(ActionCategory)`

Comment: @Kaushik It most likely doesn't matter.  Count counts non-nulls so either will work.  If NULL is involved then it needs to be `COUNT(*)` which should be your default go-to count in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this:

```
SELECT 
   Name, count(Name) as TotalAppearance
FROM
   tableName
group by Name
having count(Name) > 0
order by TotalAppearance desc;
```

You can also use order by as well.

Comment: wondering when this condition will be true `having TotalAppearance > 0
`

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by simply running following query

```
SELECT 
      Name as UniqueNames, count(Name) as occurrences
FROM
      tableName
HAVING occurrences > 0 --you may ignore this condition
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY UniqueNames
```

Comment: this is just the copied answer of @Gauravsa

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use distinct along with group by for getting the count of number of appearance as below:

```
SELECT distinct(Name), count(Name) as 'Appearance' from test_table group by Name;
```

Comment: have you checked your answer?